# how to load dataframe in pandas using multi level indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am struggling to load the following data into pandas for further analysis. The numbers at the top (EX2814823) represent different projects.

[image]

Comment: Use `df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=[0,1])`